# what should golang abi.pack argument looks like compared to solidity function

Tags: go-ethereum, uniswap, golang

The following code is a popular solidity ethereum function

```
function: swapExactETHForTokens(uint256 amountOutMin, address[] path, address to, uint256 deadline)
```

what should amountOutMin type look like in golang?

Here is what I try in golang

```go
amountOutMin := 20
data, err := routerABI.Pack("swapExactETHForTokens", amountOutMin, path, to, deadline)
```

The error message:
cannot use int as type ptr as argument

It is showed that amountOutMin is a pointer, while solidity's declaration is uint256. very confusing

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The `uint` Solidity type is a `*big.Int` in Go. So you must create a `*big.Int` variable and pass that to your contract call.

Example to set the `amountOutMin` correctly:

```
amountOutMin:= new(big.Int)
amountOutMin.SetString("5000000000000000", 10)  
data, err := routerABI.Pack("swapExactETHForTokens", amountOutMin, path, to, deadline)
```